# How to aggregate in MongoDB using value inside array?

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a list of products in my collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "product1",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": "Food",
        "subcategory": "Nuts"
      },
      {
        "category": "Candies",
        "subcategory": "Chocolate"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "product2",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": "Food",
        "subcategory": "Nuts"
      },
      {
        "category": "Candies",
        "subcategory": "Mint"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "product3",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": "Food",
        "subcategory": "Cakes"
      },
      {
        "category": "Pastries",
        "subcategory": "Chocolate"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get a count of products using aggregate. If I run

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$categories", count: { $sum: 1 }} }])
```

I get this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": [{ "category": "Food", "subcategory": "Nuts" }, { "category": "Candies", "subcategory": "Chocolate" }],
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": [{ "category": "Food", "subcategory": "Nuts" }, { "category": "Candies", "subcategory": "Mint" }],
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": [{ "category": "Food", "subcategory": "Cakes" }, { "category": "Pastries", "subcategory": "Chocolate" }],
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

But what I really need is to find count per category and subcategory, like this:

```
[
  { "_id": { "category": "Food", "subcategory": "Nuts" }, "count": 2 },
  { "_id": { "category": "Food", "subcategory": "Cakes" }, "count": 1 },
  { "_id": { "category": "Candies", "subcategory": "Chocolate" }, "count": 1 },
  { "_id": { "category": "Candies", "subcategory": "Mint" }, "count": 1 },
  { "_id": { "category": "Pastries", "subcategory": "Chocolate" }, "count": 1 }
]
```

Is there a query to obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `categories` first

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$categories"
  },
  {
    $group: { _id: "$categories", count: { $sum: 1 } }
  }
])
```